# How to cast WCHAR_T* to jstring?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm getting app crash when i try to pass WCHAR_T* to java method.

I have WCHAR_T* variable and it length.

I down know how to cast it to jstring to call java method.

my c++ code :

```
bool test(WCHAR_T* document){
    JNIEnv* jenv = getJniEnv();
    methodID_test = jenv->GetMethodID(cc, "test", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Z");
    return (bool)(jenv->CallBooleanMethod(obj,methodID_printDocument,document));
}
```

my java code :

```
public boolean test(String document) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You need to convert c-wstring to java String first.

Comment: What is `WCHAR_T`? Is it same as `wchar_t`? `wchar_t` support on android is patchy at best. Why do you use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [NewString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewString) function to convert wchar_t to jstring.

```
jstring NewString(JNIEnv *env, const jchar *unicodeChars,  jsize len);
```

Comment: NewString requires jchar* , i have WCHAR_T*. How to cast WCHAR_T* to jchar* ?

Comment: Which platform are you working on? Because it depends on the platform. I believe jchar is defined as unsigned short and it depends on the size of wchar_t and unsigned short in the underlying platform. If it's windows you can just typecast.

Comment: Then it should work. Please do verify the size once to confirm. It's been a while since I have coded JNI stuffs.

Comment: Does it? The host platform is irrelevant. If you're targeting Android you get Android's `wchar_t`, not Windows'. Android has a 4 byte `wchar_t`, which is not the same as `jchar`.

Comment: It should also be noted that just because they're the same size doesn't mean they're the same encoding. A `jchar` is UTF-16. A `wchar_t` is not necessarily unicode.

Comment: This answer was accepted, but it doesn't show the full steps to go from wchar_t to jstring.  I presume you convert wchar_t to jchar & get the size, but the answer would be more complete if you show how to do that.  For Java devs all these different string/char types are confusing!